# How to change default build directory path in Eclipse CDT when "Generate makefiles automatically" is enabled?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am working on Eclipse Neon CDT where I have to enable "Generate Make Files Automatically" at C/C++ Build Settings for my project to compile. But, once I do that the build directory grays out and am unable to find a way to change the default build directory path. How do I solve this issue?

Attached is the screenshot showing the same. I need to change the build directory from workspace/Default to workspace/target.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour. After checking "Generate Makefiles automatically", the "Build directory" text field below that remains enabled. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @HighCommander4: edited my question

Comment: Ok, I tried it again and I'm seeing the same behaviour now. Not sure what was happening before. I'll post a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't directly edit the "Build directory" when "Generate Makefiles automatically" is checked, but here is a way to indirectly get it to be what you want:

- Near the top of that dialog, click "Manage Configurations..."
- Create a new configuration with the name "target" (what you want your build directory to be named). You can copy settings from the Default configuration.
- In the dropdown next to Manage Configurations, select the newly created "target" configuration.
- Observe the Build directory change to "target" as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the answer provided by HighCommander4, and use a single period as the name of the configuration, it will default to current directory. This makes sense because from the command prompt under Linux, Windows, or Apple Desktop, issuing ***"cd .."*** will traverse to the parent directory. The use of ***"cd ."*** traverses to the current directory.